# .Net 4.0 JSON Serialization: Double quotes are changed to \"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, serialization

I'm using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer() to serialize dictionary object into JSON string. I need to send this JSON string to API sitting in the cloud. However, when we serialize it, serializer replaces all the double quotes with \"

For example -

Ideal json_string = {"k":"json", "data":"yeehaw"}

Serializer messed up json_string = {\"k\":\"json\",\"data\":\"yeehaw\" }

Any idea why it is doing so? And I also used external packages like json.net but it still doesn't fix the issues.

Code -

```
Dictionary<string, string> json_value = new Dictionary<string, string>();
json_value.Add("k", "json");
json_value.Add("data", "yeehaw");
var jsonSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string json_string = jsonSerializer.Serialize(json_value);
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using, the actual values before serialization, and how you're seeing the serialized data (e.g. in a debugger)

Comment: Thanks for your commend. I've updated my question with code. :)

Comment: You still haven't told us how you're looking at the serialized data.

Comment: I'm looking at the data via debugger (quick watch)

Comment: Right, then Marc is spot on. You *don't* actually have those backslashes, and the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @user1235159 which is exactly what I said - you're looking in the IDE. The **value** is what you wanted; simply, it is using the c# representation of that value for the reasons I already gave. The *value*, however, is exactly what you wanted. The slashes don't actually exist.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to hazard the guess that you're looking in the IDE at a breakpoint. In which case, there is no problem here. What you are seeing is perfectly valid JSON; simply the IDE is using the escaped string notation to display it to you. The **contents** of the string, however, are your "ideal" string. It uses the escaped version for various reasons:

- so that you can correctly see and identify non-text characters like tab, carriage-return, new-line, etc
- so that strings with lots of newlines can be displayed in a horizontal-based view
- so that it can be clear that it is a string, i.e. `"foo with \" a quote in"` (the outer-quotes tell you it is a string; if the inner quote wasn't escaped it would be confusing)
- so that you can copy/paste the value into the editor or immediate-window (etc) without having to add escaping yourself

Comment: No, when I sent my JSON to API, it errors out :) But I will take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: @user1235159: I suspect Marc is right about this (which is why I asked the question about how you were looking at the data) and you're actually seeing a completely *different* error.

Comment: @user1235159 to clarify - I've just run your example; the JSON that comes out is exactly what you wanted: `{"k":"json","data":"yeehaw"}`. If I look at it in the IDE, it is of course displayed as `{\"k\":\"json\",\"data\":\"yeehaw\"}`, but that doesn't change that it **is** the value you wanted.

Comment: I'm looking at the data via debugger (quick watch)

Comment: ohh..so its IDE formatting issue. Dang! I'm doing something wrong then. Thanks Marc and Jon. I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: @user1235159 Exactly. Those slashes don't actually exist; that is simply an artefact of having to display a string in a way that is most useful to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're not double serializating the object. It happened to me some days ago.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out such a rookie mistake that one can easily overlook, I for one surely did so.

Comment: Thank you for this. On my Azure Function code, I was Serializing and then doing return new JsonResult which was serializing it again.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is a [escape character](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx)

Your JSON is a `String` and when you want to have `"` in a string you must use one of the following:

```
string alias = @"My alias is ""Tx3""";
```

or

```
string alias = "My alias is \"Tx3\"";
```

**Update**

Just to clarify. What I wanted say here is that your JSON is perfectly valid. You're seeing the special characters in the IDE and that is perfectly normal like Jon & Marc are pointing in their answers and comments. Problem lies somewhere else than those `\` characters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where should I add @? Before serialization? I'm unclear on that. Thanks once again. I've also updated my question with code.